# Python error during interpolation with scipy.interpolate.Rbf. LinAlgError: singular matrix

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, spatial-interpolation

I have the dataframe `dfr` from which I am extracting the values I need.

```
x = np.array(dfr.Lon)
y = np.array(dfr.Lat)
values = np.array(dfr.val)

x=
array([ 103.9007,  103.8338,  103.8271,  103.7114,  103.9826,  103.8654,
        103.9412,  103.828 ,  103.71  ,  103.7556,  103.8657,  103.7354,
        103.8878,  103.6806,  103.8106,  103.8492,  103.7768,  103.7854,
        103.886 ,  103.8279,  103.7042,  103.7603,  103.7363,  103.8482,
        103.7953,  103.8125,  103.8907,  103.9203,  103.805 ,  103.7815,
        103.8372,  103.8202,  103.9092,  103.6351,  103.9444,  103.7205,
        103.8519,  103.8191,  103.9489,  103.7134,  103.9619,  103.8703,
        103.8697,  103.8365,  103.7013,  103.7386,  103.6184,  103.754 ,
        103.6741,  103.8461,  103.8666,  103.818 ,  103.7224,  103.8249,
        103.8577,  103.8249,  103.8577])


y =
array([ 1.3524,  1.3417,  1.3701,  1.3858,  1.3678,  1.4166,  1.3863,
        1.2745,  1.3081,  1.3329,  1.3382,  1.3262,  1.3399,  1.3455,
        1.3416,  1.3764,  1.3337,  1.4439,  1.3837,  1.25  ,  1.3275,
        1.3824,  1.4387,  1.274 ,  1.4582,  1.2937,  1.307 ,  1.3277,
        1.37  ,  1.2923,  1.3004,  1.4252,  1.4029,  1.3247,  1.3437,
        1.3302,  1.3415,  1.3191,  1.3679,  1.3505,  1.3134,  1.2799,
        1.3606,  1.3106,  1.4385,  1.3819,  1.2938,  1.281 ,  1.2542,
        1.2994,  1.3011,  1.3087,  1.3729,  1.4173,  1.3214,  1.4173,
        1.3214])

values =
array([133,  35,  53,  47,  11,  93,  26,  13,  25,  38,  74,  59,  92,
        11,  44,  73,  40,  66, 104,  11,  24,  30,  24,   5, 124,  21,
        48,  43,  42,  25,  13,  82,  59,  31,  61,  52,  53,  28,  48,
        42,  43,   9, 100,  20,  61,  47,  72,  42,  64,  13,  11,  15,
        56,  63,  38,   0,   0])
```

if I do:

```
rbf = Rbf(x, y, values, function='inverse')
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-b18c56d1a712> in <module>()
----> 1 rbf = Rbf(x, y, values, function='inverse')

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/rbf.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    220 
    221         self.A = self._init_function(r) - np.eye(self.N)*self.smooth
--> 222         self.nodes = linalg.solve(self.A, self.di)
    223 
    224     def _call_norm(self, x1, x2):

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.pyc in solve(a, b, sym_pos, lower, overwrite_a, overwrite_b, debug, check_finite)
    101         return x
    102     if info > 0:
--> 103         raise LinAlgError("singular matrix")
    104     raise ValueError('illegal value in %d-th argument of internal gesv|posv' %
    105                      -info)

LinAlgError: singular matrix
```

Comment: Looks like numerical-trouble internally. I'm not sure about your setup/task here but i'm quite sure it would work if you would standardize/normalize the data (at least subtracting the mean).

Comment: Thanks @sascha I will try  it